# Passing a dictionary to a function in viml

Tags: vim, viml

I'm building a custom unite.vim source one of the choices should be able to call a function that can accept a dictonary

```
function! s:source.gather_candidates(args, context) abort "{{{
  let l:nodeInfo = a:context.file
  return [
        \{
        \ 'word': 'delete the current node',
        \ 'kind': 'command',
        \ 'source': s:source.name,
        \ 'action__command': 'call DeleteNode(' . l:nodeInfo .')',
        \ }]
endfunction "}}}
```

And then to just test it out, echo the dictionary

```
function! DeleteNode(node) abort "{{{
  let l:currentNode = a:node
  echo l:currentNode
endfunction "}}}
```

But when I attempt to load my source, I get

```
Vim(return):E731: using Dictionary as a String
```

How can I pass the dictionary (around 24 keys) to the function?

Comment: @at whoever voted for "off-topic reason": this question is perfectly on-topic as it's a VimL programming question.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are using `:echo` and not `:echom`?

Comment: When there is an error like this, Vim usually prints out the context. Which line is Vim referring to?

Comment: 100% sure I was not using `:echom` as I write `echomsg` just to make sure I dont slip up/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: As romainl pointed out, you should be able to use `:echo` with a dictionary, unlike `:echomessage`. In that later case, you'll have needed to stringify your dictionary with `string()` function.

Thus I suspect a similar problem with the building of the action command. I'm not sure about the type of this `nodeInfo` data, but I suspect a dictionary. In case this is indeed a dictionary, you'll have to build the `action__command` dictionary entry with: `'call DeleteNode(' . string(nodeInfo) .')'`, or you could also use the new *Partials* (`:h Partial`, IIRC) if your version of Vim is recent enough (7.4.1558+), and if the code that executes this entry also supports funcrefs. They'll be much simpler to use, but definitively not portable to Vim 7.3 nor to vim 7.4.9xx...

Comment: `:echo` takes strings, numbers, dictionaries, and lists. It's `:echom` that is restricted to strings and throws `E730/E731`.

Comment: Going to make this as correct, but not sure what ended up being the issue. When I tried to pass the whole dict, errors would show. But I ended up just modifying the code to only pass the two keys I really needed. A bit messy, but it works and gives me what I need. Thanks!